# How to build a column using data from another table with contraints

Tags: database, excel, excel-2010, ms-office

I have a very-badly done Excel Database that I have to repair. To do that, I need to get specific data from a table and put it in another table, if certain cells in each rows equals cells from rows in the first table.

Here is a screenshot to explain what I need.

[image: Extracting a column depending on data from another table]

I tried with advanced filters but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer.

The trick here is to use a vertical search (=VLOOKUP(cell; tableToSearch; cellToSearchLocation) and IF conditionning.

Sadly, my example isn't valid because the cell we search (in "hey" column) is a in a column before the "ho" and "hi" columns.

If anyone has any questions about this solution, feel free to ask.